# How do I properly import, into a parent CMake project, a Protobuf-generated .h file created in a dependency CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

Here is what my project hierarchy looks like (simplified):

```
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- party
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- include
|   \-- src
|       \-- party.cc
\-- super
    +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- include
    |   \-- super.h
    \-- src
        +-- super.cc
        \-- super.proto
```

I have a library CMake project, called Super, that has some Google Protobuf code in it. A source file, `super.proto`, is used by the protoc compiler to create `super.pb.cc` and `super.pb.h`. Super's `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Super)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

set(INCLUDE_DIR "include")
set(SRC_DIR "src")

add_definitions("-std=c++11")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# === Super library ===
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(super_proto_srcs super_proto_incl ${SRC_DIR}/super.proto)
file(GLOB shared_srcs "${SRC_DIR}/*.cc")
add_library(super SHARED ${shared_srcs} ${super_proto_srcs})
target_link_libraries(super ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})

# === Install and exports ===
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)
```

Super is to become a shared library named `libsuper.so`. It has a header file that depends on `super.pb.h`.

Party is a binary that uses `libsuper.so`. It doesn't care about Protobuf, at least not directly. It includes `super.h` and calls its method. Party has a CMakeLists.txt that looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Party)

set(INCLUDE_DIR "include")
set(SRC_DIR "src")

add_definitions("-std=c++11")

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${Super_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# === Party binary ===
file(GLOB binary_srcs "${SRC_DIR}/*.cc")
add_executable(party ${binary_srcs})
target_link_libraries(party super)
```

At the level of the parent directory, the unifying `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(SuperParty)

add_subdirectory(super)
add_subdirectory(party)
```

I can build Super on its own with no errors. The Protobuf-generated files are created, also `libsuper.so`. However, when I try to build the master project, SuperParty, I get the following error:

```
In file included from superparty/party/src/party.cc:1:0:
superparty/super/include/super.h:1:22: fatal error: super.pb.h: No such file or directory
```

The file exists in SuperParty's `build/` directory, called `build/super/super.pb.h`. My problem is that I need to tell Party to include this auto-generated file, but I don't know where to get that file's path so that I can create the appropriate line in Party's `CMakeLists.txt`. Party effectively needs a reference to the CMAKE_BINARY_PATH that the master project is using.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's an automatic variable created named `Super_BINARY_DIR` that I could use in Party's `CMakeLists.txt`, but there is, in fact, an even better way to do it. Instead of modifying Party, which was already getting its list of includes from `Super_INCLUDE_DIRS`, I added a `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` to the list of includes that Super created for Party to use. Here is the new ending to Super's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# === Install and exports ===
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)
```